# Copiar a pasta de fontes usando o gulp?

Tags: php, aplicação-web, gulp, task

Como criar uma `task` para copiar a pasta de fontes do bootstrap para a pasta build? Criei a seguinte tarefa mas não está funcionando.

```
var config = {
    assets_path: './resources/assets',
    build_path: './public/build'
};

config.bower_path = config.assets_path + '/../bower_components';

config.build_path_js = config.build_path + '/js';
config.build_vendor_path_js = config.build_path_js + '/vendor';

config.build_path_html = config.build_path + '/views';
config.build_path_fonts = config.build_path + '/fonts';
config.build_path_images = config.build_path + '/images';

gulp.task('copy-fonts', function() {
    gulp.src(config.bower_path + '/bootstrap/dist/fonts/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build_path_fonts));
});
```

---

Ele nao me apresenta nenhum erro, porém a tarefa não é executada, pois a pasta fonts nem é criada na build.

Comment: Deu erro? Explica melhor esse "não está funcionnado".

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade ele não da erro, nem executa a task na verdade, a pasta fonts não é criada na pasta build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei o problema, eu não estava chamando essa função no default.
Segue o código da solução

```
gulp.task('default',['clear-build-folder'], function(){
    gulp.start('copy-fonts');
    elixir(function(mix) {
        //mix.sass('app.scss');
        mix.styles(config.vendor_path_css.concat([config.assets_path + '/css/**/*.css']), 'public/css/all.css', config.assets_path);
        mix.scripts(config.vendor_path_js.concat([config.assets_path + '/js/**/app.js']), 'public/js/all.js', config.assets_path);
        mix.version(['js/all.js', 'css/all.css']);
    });

});
```